# How to set an autoincrement composite primary key in oracle19c?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, auto-increment, composite-primary-key, oracle19c

I want to create a table, with composite primary key and autoincrement, in Oracle 19c, like this:

```
pk01 pk02 column1
==== ==== =======
1    1    abc
1    2    def
1    3    ghi
2    1    jkl
2    2    mno
3    1    pqr
1    4    stu
```

How I do it?

Comment: You have to write this logic in PL/SQL but no automatic stuff. What you need is that if 1st column value is same then second column should be incremented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create trigger on this table to achieve this result. Assume table name is test123

```
create or replace trigger trg_test123 before insert on test123
for each row
declare
v_id1 number;
v_max_id2 number;
begin
v_id1 := :new.id1;
select nvl(max(id2), 0) into v_max_id2 from test123 where id1 = v_id1;
v_max_id2 := v_max_id2 +1;
:new.id2 := v_max_id2;
end;
```

Comment: thank you very much, it's  too useful to me.

Comment: @GuillermoJesús If the solution works for you please click upvote button along with my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you create single column pk00 as pk and set it to autoincrement for storage purpose? i.e. insert the pk01 key alongwith it as usual (you need to have it). Dont have pk02 in the table but create it while querying by using window function expression: rank() over (partition by pk01 order by pk00) as pk02.

Table00
pk00 number pk
pk01 number
column1 varchar2(100)
...

...

Rest of application uses query over Table as shown below.

#######################

```
drop table table00;

create table table00 (
pk00 NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1),
pk01 number,
column1 varchar2(5),
column2 varchar2(5)
);


truncate table table00;

begin
insert into table00(pk01, column1, column2) values(1, 'abc', 'yest');
insert into table00(pk01, column1, column2) values(1, 'def', 'yest');
insert into table00(pk01, column1, column2) values(1, 'ghi', 'yest');
insert into table00(pk01, column1, column2) values(2, 'jkl', 'today');
insert into table00(pk01, column1, column2) values(2, 'mno', 'today');
insert into table00(pk01, column1, column2) values(2, 'pqr', 'today');
insert into table00(pk01, column1, column2) values(1, 'stu', 'yest');
commit;
end;
/

--select * from table00;

select
   --pk00,
   pk01,
   rank() over (partition by pk01 order by pk00) as pk02,
   column1,
   column2
from table00
order by 1,2
;



      PK01       PK02 COLUM COLUM
---------- ---------- ----- -----
         1          1 abc   yest 
         1          2 def   yest 
         1          3 ghi   yest 
         1          4 stu   yest 
         2          1 jkl   today
         2          2 mno   today
         2          3 pqr   today

7 rows selected.
```

########################